# How can I find overlapping sets of words with regex expression?

Tags: java, regex

Right now I have a regex expression that looks like `"\\w+ \\w+"` to find 2-word phrases, however, they do not overlap. For example, if my sentence was `The dog ran inside`, the output would show `"The dog", "ran inside"` when I need it to show `"The dog", "dog ran", "ran inside"`. I know there's a way to do this but I'm just way too new to using regex expressions to know how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is regex even needed here? Why not create list of words and print all n subsequent ones ?

Comment: I'm sorry I should've specified that I am using the Java Matcher and Pattern to sort through this document. I don't know how to work with these without regex.

Comment: Please post your code if possible

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a lookahead, a capturing group and a word boundary anchor:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\b(?=(\\w+ \\w+))");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible purely with regex, you can't match the same characters twice ("dog" can't be in two separate groups). Something like this doesn't need regex at all, you can simply split the string by spaces and combine it however you like:

```
>>> words = "The dog ran inside".split(" ")
>>> [" ".join(words[i:i+2]) for i in range(len(words)-1)]
['The dog', 'dog ran', 'ran inside']
```

If that doesn't solve your problem please provide more details about what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Java regexes have lookahead assertions, so of course this is possible with a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookahead to get the second word, the concatenate the non-lookahead with the lookahead part.

```
# This is Perl. The important bits:
#
# $1 is what the first parens captured.
# $2 is what the second parens captured.
# . is the concatenation operator (like Java's "+").

while (/(\w+)(?=(\s+\w+))/g) {
   my $phrase = $1 . $2; 
   ...
}
```

Sorry, don't know enough Java, but this should be easy enough to do in Java too.

Comment: Why not put both words in the lookahead and remove the need for an extra string concatenation?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker, I suppose one could use a lookbehind to achieve that `/(?<=^|\s)(?=(\w+\s+\w+))/g`, which can probably be simplified to the not-quite equivalent `/(?=(\b\w+\s+\w+))/g`

Answer (score 0):

The easy (and faster for big String) way is to use *split* :

```
    final String[] arrStr = "The dog ran inside".split(" ");
    for (int i = 0, n = arrStr.length - 1; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.format("%s %s%n", arrStr[i], arrStr[i + 1]);
    }
```

out put

```
The dog
dog ran
ran inside
```

No found trick with regex